# UL LI Menu change color when clicked not functioning

Tags: css

I used ul li for my menu on my website and I want to change the color when the user clicked

```
<div id ="navigation">
    <ul id="nav">

        <li ><a id="A1" runat="server" onserverclick ="Home_Click" shape="poly" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a  id= "A2ms" runat ="server" onserverclick ="Management_Services_Click">Management Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">aaaaaaaa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >bbbbbb</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >cccccccccccc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >ddddddddddd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Heeeeeeeeees</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >fffffffffff</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#" >gggggggggt</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#" >hhhhhhhhhhhhh</a> </li>

             </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dddfdfdf</a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#" >33333333</a> </li>
              <li><a href="#" >2222222222</a> </li>
              <li><a href="#" >11111111111</a> </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">55555555555</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">6666666666</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Vision & Values</a></li>
        <li><a id="A2" runat ="server" onserverclick ="Aboutus_Click" >About Us</a></li>
        <li><a id="A3"  runat ="server" onserverclick ="Forum_Click" >8888888888888</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

here the CSS, the mouse hover functioning perfectly but the changing the color when clicked not functioning...

```
#nav a:hover 
{
color:Orange ; 
}

  #nav a.selected 
  { 
color:Orange ; 
}
```

thanks

Comment: Where is your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS:

```
#nav a:hover 
{
    color:Orange; 
}
```

Use this in your CSS:

```
#nav a.selected, #nav a:active, #nav a:focus { 
    color:Orange; 
}
```